# PaymentMethodManager() get plugin on NULL ubercart error

Tags: 8, ubercart, payment-gateways

Hi when trying to create an order in checkout state, the order gets created however when trying to view the order it errors out with the error below:

> Error: Call to a member function getPlugin() on null in Drupal\uc_payment\Plugin\PaymentMethodManager->createFromOrder() (line 45 of /srv/bindings/6204a08fb5564631b33e310ef75fe465/code/modules/contrib/ubercart/payment/uc_payment/src/Plugin/PaymentMethodManager.php) #0 /srv/bindings/6204a08fb5564631b33e310ef75fe465/code/modules/contrib/ubercart/payment/uc_payment/src/Plugin/Ubercart/OrderPane/Payment.php(50):

Ubercart version: Version: 8.x-4.0-alpha5+227-dev

My payment methods are all setup however in order creation code we don't need payment method. Anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: Hey Prerit, thing is debugging always needs to be done by you. Otherwise this issue simply is too broad. Same when your question can only be answered with yes or no. What have you tried yourself so far to fix the problem? Or is it a bug report? Then report it on drupal.org.

Answer (score -1):

You can fix this error by applying the patch here: https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart/issues/2826324

Comment: nope thats a different issue patch